# Need help recursively iterating through all levels of a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, recursion

I am trying to create an object, and within this object will be the `name` and an array of other objects under `children`. Really I want to create a hierarchy from another object.

I have tried to create a recursive function but what I end up with is a vertical slice rather than the whole picture. I am unsure how to adjust my recursion to go back add iterate through the other horizontal objects.

```
buildHierarchy(json) {
  console.log("Entered Build Hierarchy");

  let newObject;
  newObject = this.buildChildren(json);

  console.log(newObject);
  return newObject

}
buildChildren(json) {
  let returnObject;
  for (var key in json) {
    returnObject = {
      name: key,
      children: []
    };
    var subObject = json[key];

    if (Array.isArray(subObject)) {
      returnObject = {
        name: key,
        _proficiency: subObject
      }
    } else {
      returnObject["children"].push(this.buildChildren(subObject))

    }
  }
  return returnObject;
}
```

Imagine you have this json file below

```
{users: 
  {sandy: {
    posts: [
      { title: 'Bar', comments: [ 'Ok' ] },
    ]
    followers: [
      { name: 'Foo' },
    ]
  }
 ron: {
    photos: [
      { title: 'Foo', comments: [ 'Ok' ] },
    ]
  }
 }
}
```

I am looking for something like this...

```
{
  name: "users",
  children: [
    {
      name: "sandy",
      children: [
        {
          name: "posts",
          children: [
            {
              name: "Bar",
              comments: "OK"
            }],
        { name: "followers"
          children: [
            {
              name: "Foo"
            }
          ]
        } 
      }
    ]
  },
    {
      name: "ron",
      photos: [
        {
          name: "photos",
          children: [
            {
              name: "Foo",
              comments: "OK"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: _"I am looking for something like this..."_ you should be more specific. How is `posts` getting capitalized to `Posts`? Why does `Posts` appear in the output for Sandy but not `Followers`? Why does the `Foo` post get the `Bar` comment, `OK`, and how did it go from `Ok` to `OK`?  What about the other comments? Why does `photos` appear in the output for Ron but not `likes`? Why is the `Foo` photo paired with the `Bar` comment, `Ok`? Your transformation is based on countless arbitrary decisions which you have not specified. Your question is unanswerable in its current state.

Comment: I will make sure to be more specific, I was just generalizing and wrote that up on the fly and did a bad job. I corrected the question in hopes that it is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see as the output I'm making these inferences:

- If the child object is an array, it is blindly copied to `children` key
- If the child element is an object, then they are changed to `{name: <KEY>, children: <VALUE>}`

```
function buildChildren(json) {
  let returnObject = [];
    if (typeof json !== 'object') {
    return json;
  }
  for (var key in json) {
    if (Array.isArray(json)) {
      returnObject.push(buildChildren(json[key]));
    } else {
      returnObject.push({
        name: key,
        children: buildChildren(json[key])
      });
    }
  }
  return returnObject;
}
```

Comment: Yes that is correct. In my case I am expecting the leaf nodes to be arrays. So when that is hit I want to add that array. I should have put that in the example.

Comment: @eeskonivich I just tweaked it such that it will continue to parse arrays as well until it finds a string or number. I'll revert it to the older version if you are sure that you want to stop parsing if the end value is an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function buildHierarchy(json) {
    console.log("Entered Build Hierarchy");
    let newObject;
    newObject = buildChildren(json);
    console.log(newObject);


}

function buildChildren(json) {
    if (Array.isArray(json)) {
        return {
            _proficiency: json
        }
    }

    var children = Object.keys(json);
    let final = [];
    for (var i = 0; count = children.length, i < count; i++) {
        let result = {
            name: children[i]
        }
        let d = buildChildren(json[children[i]]);
        if (d._proficiency) {
            result._proficiency = d._proficiency;
        } else {
            result.children = d;
        }
        final.push(result);
    }
    return final;
}
```

Comment: The two big things I found to be causing problems was my `key` being overwritten and having the array check inside of my loop.